# Updating column on inner left join

Tags: mysql, sql

I cannot figure out how to do inner left join update on this query (this is select query what works):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    emr AS e
    LEFT JOIN visit_ltnot AS v ON e.guid = v._pn
WHERE
    closedate='12-31-79' AND pat='00000906' AND apptstatus=''
    AND v.pdate='' AND emrdate <= '2013-11-26';
```

I need to update closedate on emr table.

I have tied following queries:

```
UPDATE emr
FROM
    emr AS e
    LEFT JOIN visit_ltnot AS v ON e.guid = v._pn SET closedate=''
WHERE
    closedate='12-31-79' AND pat='00000906' AND apptstatus=''
    AND v.pdate='' AND emrdate <= '2013-11-26';

UPDATE emr
    SET closedate=''
FROM
    emr AS e
    LEFT JOIN visit_ltnot AS v ON e.guid = v._pn
WHERE
    closedate='12-31-79' AND pat='00000906' AND apptstatus=''
    AND v.pdate='' AND emrdate <= '2013-11-26';
```

I am getting syntax errors, I need to update closedate value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MySQL, then this should work:

```
UPDATE emr e LEFT JOIN
       visit_ltnot v
       ON e.guid = v._pn
    SET closedate = ''
    WHERE closedate = '12-31-79' AND
          pat = '00000906' AND
          apptstatus = '' AND
          v.pdate = '' AND
          emrdate <= '2013-11-26';
```

Notes:

- Most importantly, `UPDATE` doesn't have a `FROM` clause in MySQL.
- The condition `v.pdate` is turning the outer join into an inner join.  So, you might as well use `inner join`.
- You should not be using date formats like `'12-31-79'`.  The correct date format is `'1979-12-31'`.
- Dates should not be stored as strings, so `v.pdate = ''` does not make sense.